# .shake.database: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)

Tags: shake-build-system

I encounter the error

```
.shake.database: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)
```

and I have the impression that it is caused by two starts of shake quickly one after the other (caused by Twitch watching file change effects). Is this a reasonable interpretation of the cause of the error?

Comment: That's really odd, since I have a lock file around Shake (which you would expect to fail if the first execution hasn't completed), and use proper resource tracking on all files so they should get closed immediately. I also have tests for the lock file, and my test suite runs 1000's of Shake runs quickly after one another. Which GHC version are you? Can you provide a way to reproduce the bug? (This might be better suited to a Shake bug report, as per https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues, but I'm happy either way)

Answer (score 0):

Shake shouldn't error out in such circumstances, so I suggest you open a bug at https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues with instructions on how to reproduce. The Shake test suite includes tests for what you describe, which doesn't provoke the error.